# How to obtain efficiently a matrix that adds all elements up to/from (i,j) in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

`P` is a given matrix (i.g., 2-dimensional array). The size of `P` is `I`×`J`.
I want to have two matrices, `A` and `B`, such that

[image]

The sizes of `A` and `B` are the same as the size of `P`.
Then, I wrote the following code in `Julia 1.6`.

```
f(P) = cumsum(cumsum(P,dims=1),dims=2)
g(P) = f( reverse!(reverse!(P,dims=1),dims=2))[end:-1:begin,end:-1:begin]
```

It works. Here is an example.

```
P = rand(1:6,3,4)

#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 4  1  1  4
# 2  2  6  6
# 3  1  5  2

f(P)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 4   5   6  10
# 6   9  16  26
# 9  13  25  37

g(P)
#3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
# 37  28  24  12
# 27  22  19   8
# 11   8   7   2
```

Does anybody have a better idea? If there is a faster method, I'd like to know.

**Context**

I want to expand the above functions `f` and `g` to tensors, that it, `P` is a tensor (i.g., `d`-dimensional array) whose size is `I1`×…×`Id`. I want to make two arrays, `A` and `B`, such that

[image]

Comment: Please put the picture of the formula instead of writing them in LaTex format since SO doesn't support LaTex, and it might be hard to follow them for users.

Comment: Writing out a loop is probably the fastest solution here. BTW: you don't need to do `[1:6;]` in the `rand` expression, just write `rand(1:6, 3, 4)`. If you have a very large range (say `1:10^9`) it would be very expensive to collect it first. For example `rand(1:10^6, 3, 4)` is >10000x faster than `rand([1:10^6;], 3, 4)`.

Comment: Dear DNF, I did not know it. I fixed the point. thank you.

Comment: A tiny bit of cleverness can be to save the storage of `B` matrix, as its elements can be calculated from `A` matrix on-the-fly using `B[i,j] == A[R,C]-(i==1 ? 0 : A[i-1,C])-(j==1 ? 0 : A[R,j-1])+(i==1 || j==1 ? 0 : A[i-1,j-1])`

Comment: The `A_ij` are sums of sub-matrices of P anchored at the top left, and the `B_ij` at the bottom right. I think this means the most efficient method is dynamic programming, where the "state matrices" end up being `A` and `B` themselves. Or maybe you need 3D arrays, the last pane of which are A and B (haven't thought about it too hard but this seems like the right track)